# Regex substring

Tags: regex, url, substring

I'm trying to select a substring using regex and I'm going round in circles.  I need to select everything before the first "_".

exampale URL - **GI_2013_JUNE_10_VOL3_LASTCHANCE**

So the result Im looking for from the URL above would be "GI".  The text before the first "_" can vary in length.

Any help would be much apprecited

Comment: Why not just use a substring function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^_]*
```

...is the expression you're looking for.

It basically says: Select everything that is not an underscore, starting at the beginning of the string.

http://regexr.com?356in

Comment: Good point. @user2335923 if the string does not contain an underscore, then use `^[^_]*` if you want to match the entire string, or `^[^_]+` if you want to match nothing. Here's an updated regexr example: http://regexr.com?356it

Comment: Ihad to tweak it slightly but the code which worked for me was ([^_]+)_.*

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be:

```
^[^_]+
```

and grab the whole regex match. But as a comment says, using a substring function is more efficient!

Comment: this has to be regex because its a web analytics tool looking at URl's

Comment: I really don't see the relationship?